# PHP File Upload Missing file Extension

Tags: php, file-upload

I am using this code for image uploads:

```
$target_dir = "../uploads/";
$uploadOk=1;

$newname =  $target_dir .'file_' . rand(0, 1000000) . '.' . end(explode(".", $_FILES["vimage1"]["name"]));

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["vimage1"]["tmp_name"], $newname)) {
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["vimage1"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
}

else {
   echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
}
```

The mystery is that I'm using this same code in one function and all works great.

I have then copied the same code to a second function and for some odd reason I keep getting upload errors because the file extension is missing from `$newname`.

Anyone have any ideas why this could be happening?

Comment: Show the function before and after changed

Comment: I'd rather use `pathinfo($_FILES["vimage1"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION)` to get the extension

Comment: Also, please provide the code for the form that's being used for uploading in the two different functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the job with this:

```
<?php
function upload($index,$destination,$maxsize=FALSE,$extensions=FALSE)
{
     if (!isset($_FILES[$index]) OR $_FILES[$index]['error'] > 0) return FALSE;

     if ($maxsize !== FALSE AND $_FILES[$index]['size'] > $maxsize) return FALSE;
   // extension
     $ext = substr(strrchr($_FILES[$index]['name'],'.'),1);
     if ($extensions !== FALSE AND !in_array($ext,$extensions)) return FALSE;
   /
     return move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$index]['tmp_name'],$destination);
}

//EXEMPLES
  $upload1 = upload('icone','uploads/monicone1',15360, array('png','gif','jpg','jpeg') );
  $upload2 = upload('mon_fichier','uploads/file112',1048576, FALSE );

  if ($upload1) "Successfully uploaded<br />";
  if ($upload2) "Failure in uploading!<br />";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not use/pass array/variable in `end()` on run time. You have to first explode the filename then pass it. something like this.

```
$proposedExtension = explode(".", $_FILES["vimage1"]["name"]);
$extension = end($imageExtension);
$newname =  $target_dir .'file_' . rand(0, 1000000) . '.'.$extension;
echo $newname;
```

it would be better to use `pathinfo($_FILES["vimage1"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION)` to get the extension of the file.